# Chain of promise.resolve() giving weird answer

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

below is the code I'm trying to understand:

example:1

```
Promise.resolve('res1')
    .then(Promise.resolve('res2'))
    .then(Promise.resolve('res3'))
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

The output is :
`res1`

But I'm not able to understand why it's res1 and not res3.
Below is the code that executes as expected:

example:2

```
    Promise.resolve('res1')
    .then(function (result1) {
        console.log(result1);
        return Promise.resolve('res2')
    })
    .then(function (result2) {
        console.log(result2);
        return Promise.resolve('res3')
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Its output is :

```
res1
res2
res3
```

As after each resolve arguement is passed on to next function, so it seems fine, but in example:1 isn't the same process followed up as in example:2, like resolving and passing the string to next function. So, I won't to understand the work flow behind it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.then` takes a callback, you aren't giving it callbacks in the first example, you're giving it  values.

Answer (score 0):

**As after each resolve arguement is passed on to next function, so it seems fine** -> Wrong, it does not get passed. The passing mechanism between the .then handlers is `return`. `Promise.resolve('res2')` is just an expression. You need to `return` the value of that expression so that it will be passed to the next .then handler.